# Rails 4 - Create a new record in a bootstrap modal from a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, crud, bootstrap-modal

I am relatively new to programming and Rails, and I have been playing around with an idea, without much success, and did not really find any answers on here, railscasts or forums, so I am turning to the community ! So here is the problem:

For the purpose of the question, I have 2 models: Supplier and Supplier Quote:

```
class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :supplier_quotes

class SupplierQuote < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :supplier
```

When I create a new Supplier Quote, there is a dropdown from which the user would select the Supplier linked to that Quote, with:

```
    <%=  f.select(:supplier_id, @supplier_select.map {|supplier| [supplier.name, supplier.id]}, include_blank: true) %>
```

If the supplier doesn't exist yet, instead of going to another page to create the record and come back, I wanted to have a modal in which the form for a new Supplier would come. So I have this link next to my dropdown:

```
<%=  link_to "Add Supplier", '#supplierModal', class: 'small-link', "data-toggle" => "modal" %>
```

And its modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="supplierModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Supplier</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

   <%= form_for(@supplier, url: {controller: 'suppliers', action: 'remote_create'} ) do |f| %>

   <h3 class="edit-title">Contact details</h3>
    <table class="pretty editlist">

      <tr>
      <th><%=  f.label(:name) %></th>
      <td><%=  f.text_field(:name) %></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <th><%=  f.label(:no_street, "Address") %></th>
      <td><%=  f.text_field(:no_street) %></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <th><%=  f.label(:city) %></th>
      <td><%=  f.text_field(:city) %></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <th><%=  f.label(:country) %></th>
      <td><%=  f.text_field(:country) %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>


    <h3 class="edit-title">Banking details</h3>
    <table class="pretty editlist">

      <tr>
      <th><%=  f.label(:bank, "Bank") %></th>
      <td><%=  f.text_field(:bank) %></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <th><%=  f.label(:IBAN, "IBAN") %></th>
      <td><%=  f.text_field(:IBAN) %></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <th><%=  f.label(:BIC, "SWIFT/BIC") %></th>
      <td><%=  f.text_field(:BIC) %></td>
      </tr> 
    </table>

   <div class="form-button">
     <%= submit_tag("Save") %>
  </div>

  <% end %>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

For now I created an action, 'remote_create' so as to not mix it up with the create action that is used in the classical way.

```
def remote_create
@supplier = Supplier.new(supplier_params)
  if @supplier.save
    redirect_to controller: 'supplier_quotes', action: 'new'
  end  
end
```

Finally within my 'new' action in supplier_quotes_controller I have the following line that allows the Supplier creation form to be generated in the modal on the Supplier Quotes 'new' view:

```
@supplier = Supplier.new
```

This doesn't work obviously, but the bigger problem is that when I submit the form in my modal, not only is the Supplier record not created, but a Supplier Quotes record is submitted and created with blank fields. So not the expected behaviour at all.

Does anyone know how I would tackle this problem? Is it a problem with the form_for, or the actions?..

Secondary question: after the creation of the form in the modal, I am using a redirect_to to the page I was already on (supplier_quotes, 'new') to refresh it, as I want the new record to show up in the dropdown. If there is a way to dynamically update the dropdown then I would just need to make the modal go away without refreshing any page. Is that possible?

Hope I was clear enough! Thanks for the help!!

Best.

A.M.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: 
My general strategy with things like this: make sure all the plumbing is connected, then do fancy stuff. So until the create is working, ditch the modal and just worry about creating a supplier from a supplier quote view. Then, get fancy with the modal.

With the `form_for` action, just use the 'classical' create route, and don't worry about defining a new one. Reference the supplier scaffolding that rails generated for you within the suppliers views (probably in the `new.html.erb` file and the `_form.html.erb` partial). You can even render the partial that rails generates from the suppliers views folder instead of writing out the form again.

Question 2:
Then when part one is creating appropriately (but still redirecting not how you want), you can take a look at remote forms, which submit in the background. The resource will be created, and you can define which pieces of the page (your dropdown menu) you want to update after a successful create action.

Read up on remote forms here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for